# JNI Callback to JAVA from Native Library

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

i am facing an issue while calling a callback from Native library to Java, The callback is being called to the Java, but from the Java function which being called i am not able to start my activity. The new Intent call returns NULL. What is the issue with my code?

Below is my Native Callback function( C Code )

```
static jclass   native_class_ID;
static jobject  native_object_ID;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jni_vm, void *reserved){
JNIEnv* env = NULL;

    if ((*jni_vm)->GetEnv(jni_vm,(void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    jclass temp  = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/test/Native_Callback"); 
    jmethodID ctor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, temp, "<init>", "()V"); 

    jobject myo = (*env)->NewObject(env, temp, ctor);

    native_class_ID = (jclass)(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,temp);
    if (native_class_ID == NULL){
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    native_object_ID = (jobject)(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,myo);
    if (native_object_ID == NULL){
        return JNI_ERR;
    }


    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef (env, temp);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef (env, myo);

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}


//Below is the function called when an event occurs in native library
{
methodID = (*pEnv)->GetMethodID(pEnv, native_class_ID , "notify_action_complete", "()V")
(*pEnv)->CallVoidMethod(pEnv, native_object_ID , methodID, NULL);
}
```

Below is my Java Code

```
public class Native_Callback extends AppCompatActivity{
.
.
.
    public void notify_action_complete() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoPlayback.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
.
.
.
}
```

The notify_action_complete has been successfully called when a particular event occurs in Native Side, but why my activity is not starting? I am new to java, please help me with this

**NOTE :** ClassID/ObjectID was stored in native side during JNI_Onload()

My requirement is to start VideoPlayback activity when notify_action_complete() is recieved. During the time when the callback been recieved, my application runs with a waiting_screen activity.

Comment: How are you creating the `Native_Callback` instance exactly? It seems weird to have an `Activity` as your callback listener. I mean, what if that Activity has been destroyed before you get the callback?

Comment: @Michael i am just loading the Native_Callback classID in the native library and my requirement is to start the VideoPlayback activity when notify_action_complete() callback is received from the native library.

Comment: @Michael and also i am not able to call any different class method from notify_action_complete(), unless the class instance is declared globally

Comment: Can you show how control flows from the root Android activity to your JNI code? Is your JNI code on a different thread, perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure you can reuse object references across calls, i.e. your objectID is probably not valid anymore. What does `ExceptionDescribe` say?

Comment: @Botje Yes my JNI code is in a different thread, it attaches to the java thread when a callback is recieved .

Comment: @user2543253 i am storing objectID has a global reference in the native library during JNIOnLoad(), so i can use it for future reference.

Comment: This is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because the part which calls to JNI, as well as the definition of the JNI, had not been provided. You'd have to provide more of the code, else this is difficult to understand. For extended JNI checking on a physical device, run `adb shell setprop debug.checkjni 1`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler i have provided more code on how JNI callback method is implemented, Actually i am getting the callback from Native Library -> Java, but inside my java function notify_action_complete() i am not able to start any activity.

Comment: @Maddy26 I've rather meant the Java bindings (were the naming of the methods plays a role). However... just set a break-point at `startActivity(intent)` to see what's wrong with the `Intent` - and if there is a `Context`.

Comment: `public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SomeNativeCallback` would rather be readable, since in Java callback listeners are represented as the implementation of an `interface` (which can be defined as required).

Comment: Nope. Better just get your semantics right, so that one cold even read it; it is annoying to read that already. Why the ... you call references to the Java domain `native_class_ID` & `native_object_ID`? When something is difficult, one should write is as explicit as possible - and you didn't follow up on my suggesting to set a break-point.

Comment: You need to error-check every JNI call, and call one of the JNI Exception methods if it fails.